# ExNavigator in react-native can't find Router

Tags: react-native

My routes were working fine with the built-in NavigatorIOS, but I wanted to add a custom font to the navigation so I decided to go with ExNavigator. I'm open to other component solutions, but first here is my problem:

From my initial route, the user is supposed to go to a detail view onPress. The initial route is loading, but the detail view is not working with ExNavigator.

I made an object for the router following exponent's docs. When the onPress event is triggered, I get an error: Can't find variable: Route

Here are some code snippets

app.js

```
    class app extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <ExNavigator
            style={styles.container}
             translucent={false}
            initialRoute={
              Router.getHomeRoute()
            }/>
        );
      }
    }

    let router = {...}

    export default Router;
```

main.js

```
  <TouchableHighlight underlayColor={'#f3f3f2'}
          onPress={()=>this.selectRow(row)}>

  selectRow: function(row){

      row = {row};
      let route = Router.getDetailRoute(row);
      this.props.navigator.push(route);

  }
```

for detail.js i'm just including NavigatorIOS.

I get a react error if I try and put the router in any other file but app.js.